# How to keep the digit limit if a column in Dataframe while reading from csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading csv files as pandas dataframe. There is a column called "c_id" which contains only numbers. It will be 3 digit numbers. below is the csv content

```
doc_id,c_id,functional_area,doc_type,capture_date,file_name
011,"023","AP","AP - CHECKS","2021-05-01","file-11"
012,"023","AP","AP - CHECKS","2021-05-02","file-12"
013,"023","AP","AP - CHECKS","2021-05-01","file-13"
014,"023","AP","AP - CHECKS","2021-05-01","file-13"
```

possible other values of c_id : "23", 23, 005, 9, 234, 430 etc.

When i read it as pandas dataframe i need to keep the column as 3 digit column. So

if in csv,

```
"23" it should be 023 in dataframe. similarly
23 -> 023,
005 -> 005
9 -> 009 etc.
```

How can i achieve this?

```
dtypes = {'c_id': 'str'}   
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype = dtypes)
```

I tried with dtypes as well. But didn't get the required results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed solution works for me:

```
In [1]: df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype={'c_id': 'str'})

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   doc_id c_id functional_area     doc_type capture_date file_name
0      11  023              AP  AP - CHECKS   2021-05-01   file-11
1      12  023              AP  AP - CHECKS   2021-05-02   file-12
2      13  023              AP  AP - CHECKS   2021-05-01   file-13
3      14  023              AP  AP - CHECKS   2021-05-01   file-13
```

If you want to add zero-padding to strings that don't have the right length you can use `Series.str.zfill`:

```
df['c_id'] = df['c_id'].str.zfill(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use `.str.zfill` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"c_id":["23","005","9"]})
df["c_id"] = df["c_id"].str.zfill(3)
print(df)
```

output

```
  c_id
0  023
1  005
2  009
```

Explanation: `zfill` pads with 0s to get desired width (3 in this case), if given str is already as long or longer nothing will happen to it.